# Making sure that BUnit package and test packages is not included on Production Code

Tags: java, unit-testing, blackberry, java-me

I have a project in Blackberry and recently I implemented BUnit for this project. I created another folder where my new UiApplication (which is BUnit and test classes) were placed. I am enabling BUnit by adding an alternate entry point on my application and adding an Application argument. I can disable BUnit by deleting the Application Argument from the Alternate entry point. Now my problem is I want to make sure that BUnit codes and test classes are not included on my Production code so that the .cod file will not bloat. How am I going to achieved it? How about if I pre-processed the code which calls my BUnit? Are the orphan classes will not be add on my production code?

For my building process, I use eclipse IDE.

Comment: Which build system are you using?  Are you just using your IDE, or are you using a tool like Ant (+Ivy?), Maven, or Gradle?  There are different techniques for each.

Comment: I am using IDE, eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Just like the *Source Filtering* on **Netbeans**, **Eclipse** has *Resource Filter* where we can exclude or include files during our build. You can find the Resource Filter when you right click on *Project*->*Properties*->*Resource*->*Resource Filters*. When you see a red exclamation mark on the project root folder after you exclude or include a folder or file on your *Resource Filters* you need to edit the project's *Build Path* and on *Source* tab just delete the specified folder that you don't want to include on your final build. In my case the **BUnit** package and my test classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use Preprocessor Directives. Check following links for more details.

> - [Specifying preprocessor directives](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp)
> - [Preprocessor directives in  Blackberry](http://javatechig.com/2010/08/27/preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry/)
> - [Coding for Multiple Blackberry Devices - Using Preprocessor
>     Directives in Eclipse](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html)
> - [How to specify a preprocessor directive in eclipse?](http://gosago.com/a/json/how-to-specify-a-preprocessor-directive-in-eclipse.html)
> - [Preprocessor Directives for Blackberry](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/preprocessor-directives-blackberry/)
> - [Preprocessor Directives for JDE](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Preprocessor-Directives-for-JDE/m-p/72094#M8277)

Also check following StackOverflow questions and answers.

> - [Using preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for
>     eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse)
> - [Preprocessor directives supported by the RIM compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179129/preprocessor-directives-supported-by-the-rim-compiler)
> - [how to use preprocessors in blackberry to target the code for
>     multiple platforms, any one having any thing on JDE with 4.2 and
>     above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665587/how-to-use-preprocessors-in-blackberry-to-target-the-code-for-multiple-platforms)

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the reply. My main concern here is the whole package of BUnit and my other test packages. When I use preprocessor on the part where the calling of my TestRunner I know that I can enable or disable the BUnit but the problem is even if the BUnit is disabled the whole package of it still affects the size of my .cod.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem well. In JDE it is possible to maintain different project definition file (.jdp) for a single project, and the ,jdp file itself list all the java classes and resources (images, audio files, jars etc) those needed to be packaged in .cod file. I think something similar can be done with Eclipse to exclude unnecessary resources while building .cod.

Comment: I see, just like Source Filtering on Netbeans. Will search for that on eclipse. thanks.